# how to convert a base64 encoded public key to crypto.PublicKey or a ecdsa.PublicKey

Tags: go, public-key

As the question states can anyone show me how I can convert a `base64` encoded public key into a `crypto.PublicKey` or a `ecdsa.PublicKey` ? I am unable to find an example of this online. Any documentation or snippets on this regard would be appreciated

Comment: Look at: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509@go1.20.1#ParsePKIXPublicKey or https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509@go1.20.1#ParsePKCS1PublicKey

Comment: Can you provide an example of a public key you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ECDSA` was specifically mentioned, `ParsePKIXPublicKey` should be the function to use, as noted in the comments to the questions. `ParsePKCS1PublicKey` would be for an RSA public key in an older format (recognizable by the header `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`). By the way, `ParsePKIXPublicKey` can also parse RSA public keys in the newer format (recognizable by the header `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`, note the missing `RSA`) - using the encoded key type object identifier. Besides ECDSA and RSA also DSA and ED25519 are supported.

Here is a complete, self-contained example showing the creation of sample keys with openssl in `ECDSA` and `RSA` formats and reading the public key with Go.

**Generation of an RSA public key**

```
openssl genrsa -out rsaPrivateKey.pem 1024  
openssl rsa -in rsaPrivateKey.pem -pubout > rsaPublicKey.pem
```

**Generation of an ECDSA public key**

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -out ecdsaPrivateKey.pem 
openssl ec -in ecdsaPrivateKey.pem -pubout -out ecdsaPublicKey.pem
```

**Test**

A test might look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/dsa"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/ed25519"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    rsaPublicKey, err := readPublicKey("rsaPublicKey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = printPublicKey(rsaPublicKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ecdsaPublicKey, err := readPublicKey("ecdsaPublicKey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = printPublicKey(ecdsaPublicKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Here two functions `readPublicKey` and `printPublicKey` are used, which respectively read and print the PEM file with the public key.

As shown in the documentation, the code to read an RSA or ECDSA key would be the same:

```
func readPublicKey(filename string) (pub any, err error) {
    publicKey, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    block, _ := pem.Decode(publicKey)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("decoding public key PEM failed")
    }

    pub, err = x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return pub, nil
}
```

Finally, the data can be easily accessed with a type switch, as nicely illustrated in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509@go1.20.1#ParsePKIXPublicKey) referenced in the comment.

```
func printPublicKey(pub any) error {
    switch pub := pub.(type) {
    case *rsa.PublicKey:
        fmt.Println("pub is of type RSA:", pub)
    case *dsa.PublicKey:
        fmt.Println("pub is of type DSA:", pub)
    case *ecdsa.PublicKey:
        fmt.Println("pub is of type ECDSA:", pub)
    case ed25519.PublicKey:
        fmt.Println("pub is of type Ed25519:", pub)
    default:
        return errors.New("unknown type of public key")
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Differentiation of the key types**

Using the cool online ASN.1 JavaScript decoder https://lapo.it/asn1js/ one can feed in the generated ECDSA pem.

The will reveal in the first object identifer `ecPublicKey (ANSI X9.62 public key type)`.

Whereas for `RSA` this would be `rsaEncryption (PKCS #1)`.

**secp256k1**

Not all curve types are supported by Go's crypto package, notably `secp256k1`. You can identify the curve type, for example, by the second object identifier in the online tool mentioned above.

Attempting to use the above code with it would produce the following error message: `x509: unsupported elliptic curve`.

In such case, you could for example use the package `github.com/decred/dcrd/secp256k1`.

To get the appropriate input form for `secp256k1.ParsePubKey`, e.g. the uncompressed key format (0x04 + x + y) can be used, which in turn can be extracted via `Unmarshal` from the `asn1` package (see also to the internals of `ParsePKIXPublicKey`).

**Self-contained example**

**Generation of an ECDSA public key with secp256k1 curve type**

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -out ecdsaSecp256k1PrivateKey.pem
openssl ec -in ecdsaSecp256k1PrivateKey.pem -pubout -out ecdsaSecp256k1PublicKey.pem
```

A self-contained example for testing might look something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/asn1"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/decred/dcrd/dcrec/secp256k1"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type publicKeyInfo struct {
    Raw       asn1.RawContent
    Algorithm pkix.AlgorithmIdentifier
    PublicKey asn1.BitString
}

func readSecp256k1PublicKey(filename string) (*secp256k1.PublicKey, error) {
    publicKey, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    block, _ := pem.Decode(publicKey)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("decoding public key PEM failed")
    }
    var pki publicKeyInfo
    if _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(block.Bytes, &pki); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    pub, err := secp256k1.ParsePubKey(pki.PublicKey.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return pub, nil
}

func main() {
    pub, err := readSecp256k1PublicKey("ecdsaSecp256k1PublicKey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("public key %T", pub)
}
```

The output on the debug console would be:

```
public key *secp256k1.PublicKey
```